# Автоматический сдвиг элементов при наезде на них меню

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, bootstrap

Я уже [писал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/652985/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F?noredirect=1#comment935282_652985) такой вопрос.

Изначально все выглядит так.

- Категории находятся слева.
- Использую bootstrap для блюд и вообще на сайте.

Можете подсказать как сделать так? При открытии категории, нужно смещать блюда на `col-md-offset-3`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Например, так. Если категорий/подкатегорий будет больше, то нужно делать offset дальше для блюд которые находятся слева. Вообще не знаю, как это сделать. Делать вместо меня не нужно, хотя бы подсказать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот у меня появились его наработки.

```js
var blockRect = document.querySelector('.block').getBoundingClientRect();
var foods = document.querySelectorAll('.food');

function toggleSubCategories(_category, init) {

  if (!init) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.subcategory').forEach(function(category) {
      if (category !== _category) {
        category.classList.remove('show');
      }
    });

    _category.classList.toggle('show');
  }

}

function isOpenListStructure() {
  return document.querySelectorAll('.subcategory.show').length === 0 ? false : true;
}

function foodOffset(category, init) {
  var subcategories = document.querySelector('.list-structure > ul');
  var offsetListToFood = subcategories.offsetHeight - blockRect.height;
  toggleSubCategories(category.children[1], init);
  var isOpen = isOpenListStructure();

  if (subcategories.offsetHeight >= blockRect.height) {
    
    foods.forEach(function(food, index) {
      var nextFoodIndex = index;
      var foodRectData = food.getBoundingClientRect();
      
      // detect left foods
      if (foodRectData.left <= blockRect.left) {
        var absoluteFoodHeight = foodRectData.height + foodRectData.top;
        var absoluteListHeight = subcategories.offsetHeight + Math.abs(subcategories.getBoundingClientRect().top);
        
        console.log(food, 'subcategories.offsetHeight ', subcategories.offsetHeight, ' > ', foodRectData.top, ' && ', subcategories.offsetHeight, ' < ', absoluteFoodHeight);
        
        if ( absoluteListHeight >= foodRectData.top && absoluteListHeight <= absoluteFoodHeight ) {
          food.classList.add('col-md-offset-4');
        } else {
          food.classList.remove('col-md-offset-4');
        }

      }

    });
  } else {
    document.querySelectorAll('.food').forEach(function (food) {
      if (food.classList.contains('col-md-offset-4')) {
        food.classList.remove('col-md-offset-4');
      }
    });
  }
}

document.querySelectorAll('.category').forEach(function(category) {
  foodOffset(category, true);
  category.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    foodOffset(this, false);
  });
});
```

```css
.list-structure {
  position: relative;
}

.list-structure li {
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.list-structure li a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 11px 10px 7px 31px;
  display: block;
}

.list-structure li {
  display: block;
  background: #546a88;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.list-structure > ul {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100% height: 100%;
}

.categories {
  padding: 10px;
}

.subcategory {
  display: none;
}

.block {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 200px;
}

.food {
  padding: 10px;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 categories">
    <div class="list-structure">
      <ul>
        <li class="category">
          <a href="#">Маки/Суши</a>
          <ul class=" subcategory">
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="category">
          <a href="#">Салаты/Супы</a>
          <ul class=" subcategory">
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="category">
          <a href="#">Салаты/Супы</a>
          <ul class=" subcategory">
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="category">
          <a href="#">Салаты/Супы</a>
          <ul class=" subcategory">
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="category">
          <a href="#">Горячие блюда</a>
          <ul class=" subcategory">
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="category">
          <a href="#">Десерты</a>
          <ul class=" subcategory">
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="category">
          <a href="#">Напитки</a>
          <ul class=" subcategory">
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9 block">
    asdsakjdslkajdklsad
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 food"><img src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/food-profile_image-0a2c3ed2f8d119ea-300x300.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 food"><img src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/food-profile_image-0a2c3ed2f8d119ea-300x300.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 food"><img src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/food-profile_image-0a2c3ed2f8d119ea-300x300.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 food"><img src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/food-profile_image-0a2c3ed2f8d119ea-300x300.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 food"><img src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/food-profile_image-0a2c3ed2f8d119ea-300x300.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 food"><img src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/food-profile_image-0a2c3ed2f8d119ea-300x300.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 food"><img src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/food-profile_image-0a2c3ed2f8d119ea-300x300.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 food"><img src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/food-profile_image-0a2c3ed2f8d119ea-300x300.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 food"><img src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/food-profile_image-0a2c3ed2f8d119ea-300x300.png" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

Код лучше смотреть если развернуть `result` на весь экран. Прикрепляю ссылку на [codepen](http://codepen.io/Insidexa/pen/PmwaNL).

Проблема заключается в том, что при раскрытии категории "Напитки", первый блок сдвигается, это правильно, но следующий слева остается на месте, и 3 сдвигается.

Я знаю что это происходит из-за сдвига, но я не знаю как это исправить.

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте - определил некий максимум для высоты раскрытого меню. Если высота превышает максиму - тоглил бы класс на `body`, например. И по этому классу - просто менял стили. Т.е. js'а тут будет вообще децл.

Comment: как вы могли увидеть, с `css` будет проблема т.к. верстальщик сделал список с категориями `absolute`

Comment: А в чём заключается проблема с `absolute`?

Comment: @YozhEzhi я не понимаю как мне класс для `body` поможет

Comment: Можно будет, используя класс на body, прописать стили для плитки с товарами. Например, можно будет добавить `padding-left`, равный ширине навигации. Таким образом - плитка с товарами сдвинется вправо.

Comment: @YozhEzhi к сожалению так не пойдет, я так уже делал, но нужно именно что бы не все, а те на которые наезжает список с категориями

Comment: А вы подумали про пользователей вашего сайта которые будут страдать из-за непостоянного положения товаров?

Comment: Сайт делаю не себе, требование заказчика

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переверстал ваши блоки, в итоге решилось все простым CSS.

```js
function toggleSubCategories(_category, init) {
  if (!init) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.subcategory').forEach(function(category) {
      if (category !== _category) {
        category.classList.remove('show');
      }
    });
    _category.classList.toggle('show');
  }
}

document.querySelectorAll('.category').forEach(function(category) {
  toggleSubCategories(category.children[1], true);
  category.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    toggleSubCategories(category.children[1], false);
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
.list-structure,
.block {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.list-structure > ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.list-structure li {
  background: #546a88;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.list-structure li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.list-structure li a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 11px 10px 7px 31px;
}

.subcategory {
  display: none;
}

.block {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 257px;
}

.food {
  padding: 10px;
}

.food img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="list-structure">
        <ul>
          <li class="category">
            <a href="#">Маки/Суши</a>
            <ul class=" subcategory">
              <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="category">
            <a href="#">Салаты/Супы</a>
            <ul class=" subcategory">
              <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="category">
            <a href="#">Салаты/Супы</a>
            <ul class=" subcategory">
              <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="category">
            <a href="#">Салаты/Супы</a>
            <ul class=" subcategory">
              <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="category">
            <a href="#">Горячие блюда</a>
            <ul class=" subcategory">
              <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="category">
            <a href="#">Десерты</a>
            <ul class=" subcategory">
              <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li class="category">
            <a href="#">Напитки</a>
            <ul class=" subcategory">
              <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <div class="block">
        Site header
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 food"><img src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/food-profile_image-0a2c3ed2f8d119ea-300x300.png" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 food"><img src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/food-profile_image-0a2c3ed2f8d119ea-300x300.png" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 food"><img src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/food-profile_image-0a2c3ed2f8d119ea-300x300.png" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 food"><img src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/food-profile_image-0a2c3ed2f8d119ea-300x300.png" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 food"><img src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/food-profile_image-0a2c3ed2f8d119ea-300x300.png" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 food"><img src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/food-profile_image-0a2c3ed2f8d119ea-300x300.png" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 food"><img src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/food-profile_image-0a2c3ed2f8d119ea-300x300.png" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 food"><img src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/food-profile_image-0a2c3ed2f8d119ea-300x300.png" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 food"><img src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/food-profile_image-0a2c3ed2f8d119ea-300x300.png" alt=""></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Или смотреть код на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gambala/w48kpps2/).

Comment: Огромное спасибо Вам